# How can I (safely) interrupt a computation on a separate thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, mfc, thread-safety

I have a program which uses a 3rd party library to do some computation which I launch on a separate thread from my main application.
Unfortunately, this computation can take extremely long and does not provide an interface for progress updates and cancellation.

In order to have such an interface, I want to create a "Cancel" button which should immediately terminate the computation (and trash all results).

I would require some help (-code snipped appreciated-) with how this is best set-up and cleanly executed. Is it 'safe' to do it?

I'm currently using `AfxBeginThread()` to launch the process.

Comment: Unless the 3rd-party library have some kind of polling for cancellation there's not much you can do. You could just ignore the thread and discard any result it produces.

Comment: If you are launching the thread natively with C++ code you can fetch the native handle from the thread and also call `pthread_kill` to send a signal to the thread ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Curious pthread_kill on MS Windows (mfc!)?

Comment: @Aconcagua whoops, I didn't even know what mfc is

Comment: It is possible to kill threads; ***not safely***. Basically "safely" is the operative word that makes this impossible.

Comment: The root issue is that only the OS can reliably terminate threads and, with typical languages/apps, it's only at process termination time that this is 'safe'.

Comment: There are umm.. things.. you can do.  One is to design your app so that the thread/s in question can be orphaned safely, ie. set to the lowest priority, have a 'don't bother sending any results when you're eventually done' flag, and can so be ignored until they die alone in peace.  Essentially, what @Someprogrammerdude suggests above.

Comment: Other 'designs' might corrupt the data upon which the thread is operating on in such a way that an exception is raised, bubbles out of the library call and so allows the thread to terminate early.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Destroying (or pausing) a thread which is not running your code, is an exercise in breaking your program.

If there is code within the thread which

```
EnterCriticalSection( &cs );
// do something
LeaveCriticalSection( &cs );
```

Then the resource cs will be permanently owned by the destroyed (or paused thread).  This will then deadlock when the resource is required anywhere else.

If the thread is creating other resources such as files, shared memory, these can also be leaked adding to your programs instability.

If the thread has a cancel call-back, this should be used.  I have also tried forms of error injection, when the thread was asking for data, and these ended up "testing" the third-party code, leaving it executing untested and buggy paths.

Talk to the supplier and ask for a cancel method, or look for alternatives.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any call-back interface I can use. I *thought* that killing the thread is not only ugly, but dangerous, but I was *hoping* somebody would tell me otherwise here...

Comment: @BmyGuest if the 3rd-party library doesn't open files, nor allocate memory or other system resources, but only performs calculations, then  killing the thread with [TerminateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx) might be an option, although rather an ugly one.

Comment: @BmyGuest another less ugly option could be to outsource the calculation to another .exe, which you can kill if necessary using [TerminateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx). Killing a process this way isn't very clean either, but it's less error prone that killing the thread, because all resources the 3rd party library will allocate will be freed by the system when the process is killed.

Comment: @MichaelWalz _all resources the 3rd party library will allocate will be freed by the system_ ... except things like temp files.

Comment: @zett42 true, but that's not so important, because 1. the temp directory contains a lot more crap anyway. 2. If you know what temporary files the 3rd party library creates, nothing stops you from cleaning them up yourself. 3. You can launch the process with a special environnment, so that TEMP and TMP point to another temporary directory than the standard one and then just clean up that directory. Anyway I wrote that this is not very clean either.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to spawn a child process to perform these long computations. Unlike thread, a process can be terminated without negative consequences for main application. This approach will also protect main application in case of critical errors in third-party code, such as access violation that would otherwise kill it.

Comment: That's more or less what I suggested in my comment to mksteve's answer.